# Ruby logic in header does not work corrrectly when using redirect_to after log in (with jquery mobile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, redirect, jquery-mobile

Update: The problem below occurs when I add:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

I'm trying to redirect to a landing page after the user has logged in but the variables I set in application_controller.rb are not reflected in the page I redirect to.

My sessions_controller.rb looks like this:

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to '/landingpage', :notice => "Logged in!"
```

My application.html.erb looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <%= yield :head %>       
</head>
<body>
    <%= yield :body1%>
</body>
```

My view for landing page looks like this:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
    <% if current_user %>
       <script>'function test(){alert('user is signed in')}'</script>
    <% else %>
       <script>'function test(){alert('user is not signed in')}'</script>
    <% end %>
<% content_for :body1 do %>
    <% if current_user %>
       User is signed in 
    <% else %>
      User is not signed in
    <% end %>
    <button onClick="test();">test</button>
<% end %>
```

**The result:** After signing in, the page displays "User is signed in" but the function still returns user is not signed in. However, if I click refresh in the browser, it loads everything properly.

I'm tring to understand why using redirect does not update the header info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with jquery mobile, here is the solution that worked:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Enter this section between the the .js links --> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    });
</script>
<!-- End section -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work, if you have below way. Can you paste your `<% content_for :head do %>` code?

You have to put yield call in the layout, and each view's template is where you put the content_for block.

**In app/views/layouts/application.html.erb put**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <%= yield :head %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= yield :body1 %>
    <%= yield %>
</body>
```

**Then in each view, you can do this:**

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <h1>My Header!</h1>
<% end %>

<% content_for :body1 do %>
    <h3>Body1</h3>
<% end %>

<h3>The rest of the page</h3>
```

Comment: Ok, now I get 'Body1' and 'The rest of the page'.  However, :head does not display the right info.  It seems to display the data I added prior to the redirect.

Comment: Just rewrote the question based on new findings.  Seems like the header info does not update

Comment: How you get current_user in application_controller.rb or Helper? Can you paste the code please?